# 2-phases connected to single rectifier

Tags: rectifier, three-phase

I have come across an unusual part of a circuit that I hope someone could shed some light on and I have redrawn in LTSPICE. The circuit is to measure voltage of a 3-phase generator. Two of the phases R and S are measured and applied to the rectifier shown below. The "+" and "-" are then fed into a differential amp.
It is unusual to see the second phase applied to the lower half of the circuit shown.

[image]

[image]

Why would this configuration be used and is there any advantages/disadvantages to using it this way.

Comment: That milliohm resistor is ... concerning. There may be disadvantages to that part.

Comment: @Brian Those two diodes in series hurts my eyes too.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! Please show where you find said circuit so everyone can avoid it and state your question.

Comment: Just to clarify @BrianDrummond's comment (in case you're not aware of it), `1m` is the same as `1 milli`. If you want `1 mega`, then you have to write `1meg`, or simply `1e6`. Note that SPICE, in general, is case *insensitive*.

Comment: I remeasured the resistor and edited the circuit, its actually 3.3Meg but this has no effect on the output. I have shown the positive and negative outputs. This still presents the same question, why would one apply a phase to the lower part of the circuit. Has anyone ever come across something like this before.

Comment: Is this 3 phase Y-connected or delta-connected?  If delta, then you may not have a "common" or ground, and connecting across two phases is the only way to read the voltage.  Also, the two diodes in series could be there to split the reverse bias voltage across them, or perhaps for reliability (diodes usually fail shorted, so the circuit still works and doesn't short out if one diode fails).

Comment: Its a phase to phase measurement that bit is fine but I fail to see why a somewhat rectified signal and a pure sine wave would be fed to a differential amp to do a voltage measurement.